# calling method from another activity android

Tags: android

I have methods in a class, MainActivity, that I want to move to another class to clean up a bit.

When I call this method from mainactivity it works perfectly.
When I call it from the other class, mainactivity2, I get java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is how I am calling it from MainActivity:
MainActivity2 ma = new MainActivity2();
ma.onLongClick();

My MainActivity2 extends MainActivity

Sorry for the stupid questions, but I am confused as to why I am having this problem as I thought I knew how to call methods from other classes...

Comment: do you want to access one class's method inside your main activity class? or?

Comment: You are creating new instances of your activities?

Comment: Sorry, I want to call the method onLongClick(); that is located in MainActivity2 in MainActivity.

Comment: This is something not possible with the activity. If you want, you change your code and support fragment

Comment: Please create a compilable example with the two classes, but only what is strictly necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- MainActivity2 doesn't extend MainActivity
- I use the following code: `new MainActivity2().onLongClick();`

Try it and tell if it works ;)